# JavaScript regex look behind alternative

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to match the following string into 2 groups using look behind but apparently, they are not supported in JavaScript.

**Regex:** `((?<=:).*(?=;))|((?<=,).*$)`  <kbd>[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8SzGPY/1/)</kbd>

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/abcd1234...

--> group1: image/jpeg
--> group2: /abcd1234...
```

Then I tried to use [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp) library hoping it would support look behind but still no success.

```
var XRegExp = require("xregexp");
var base64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/abcd1234...";
base64 = XRegExp.matchRecursive(base64, '((?<=:).*(?=;))|((?<=,).*$)', 'g');
```

But I get the following error:

```
node_modules/xregexp/xregexp-all.js:3376
        new RegExp(generated.pattern, generated.flags),
        ^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /((?<=:).*(?=;))|((?<=,).*$)/: Invalid group at new RegExp (native)
```

Is there a way to run the regex using JavaScript's native regex parser probably by reversing the string?

Comment: Why are you trying to pick apart a data URL? Where is it coming from, and what do you plan to do with it?

Comment: @torazaburo My highest priority is to extract mime type from it

Comment: I would prefer to GET the URL with `responseType` set to Blob, then consult the `type` property of the resulting blob.

Comment: Why do you need a lookbehind? Can't you just do `:(.*);|,(.*$)`?

Comment: Look-behinds were added in the 2018 specification. They work in Chrome, but Firefox has a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665) due to lack of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be more specific:

```
(?=[^:;]*;)([^:;]+)|([^;,]+)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fw5xiD/1)

Or use more JS:

```js
var re = /:([^:;]+);|,(.*)$/g;
var str = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/abcd1234...";
var matches;
while ((matches = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(matches[1] ? matches[1] : matches[2])
}
```